# How to set data in a row of RecyclerView using DataBinding in MVVM/retrofit Architecture?

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, retrofit

I am having a problem, I am trying to implement data binding in simple project, I have made an example using only one object, it is simple and has worked, but now I am trying to do that to a list, which is more hard because I am dealing now with adapter.

So now my xml layout is inside a layout tag and declared a variable in the xml defining the model I want to integrate, my activity_main is also inside layout tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >
    <data>
        <variable
            name="contract"
            type="com.example.cosysimulation.models.ContractModel" />
    </data>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/courtier"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:text="@{contract.courtier}"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/contratImage"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"></TextView>
</layout>
```

This is my activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ContractsListViewModel contractsListViewModel;

    @BindView(R.id.contractList)
    RecyclerView contractList;

    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActivityMainBinding main = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);


        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        contractList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        contractsListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ContractsListViewModel.class);
        contractsListViewModel.call();

        contractsListViewModel.contractList.observe(this,contractModels -> {
            adapter = new ContractListAdapter(MainActivity.this, contractModels);
            contractList.setAdapter(adapter);
        });

    }
}
```

This is my Adapter :

```
public class ContractListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContractListAdapter.ContractViewHolder> {

    List<ContractModel> contracts;
    Context context;
    public ContractListAdapter(Context context, List<ContractModel> contracts){
        this.context = context;
        this.contracts = contracts;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ContractViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contrat, parent, false);
        return new ContractViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ContractViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(contracts.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.contracts.size();
    }

    public class ContractViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        @BindView(R.id.courtier)
        TextView courtier;

        @BindView(R.id.contratImage)
        ImageView contractImage;

        public ContractViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

       }

        public void bind(ContractModel contractModel){
            courtier.setText(contractModel.getCourtier());
        }

    }
}
```

This is my ContractModel :

public class ContractModel {

```
@SerializedName("courtier")
private String courtier;


public ContractModel(String courtier) {
    this.courtier = courtier;
}

public String getCourtier() {
    return courtier;
}

public void setCourtier(String courtier) {
    this.courtier = courtier;
}
```

}

Any help would be much appreciated, the tutorials I found on Youtube are showing mostly the binding of only one object which is easier.

Comment: Hi, are you using ButterKnife library

Comment: @Zain Yes, using it

Comment: So, you surely want to use DataBinding Library instead?

Comment: Yes, I can remove the butterKnife to us completly the MVVM because that s what I am looking for

Comment: can you please show `ContractModel`?

Comment: Check edit, I have edited

Comment: list item ? it is already there, it's the first one

Comment: sorry I got it .. just thought it is the main layout

Comment: Hope my answer solve your question.. Eager to know your feedback or if you need further help

Comment: I will check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you mainly asking for using `DataBinding` library with `RecyclerView` adapter.

First I just manipulated your main class to be adapted with `DataBinding`, by just inflating your `RecyclerView` using data binding, and omit using `ButterKnife` library.

you can inflate views in your layout into java with the `DataBinding` object of your activity, and using their IDs, here the `DataBinding` library adapts IDs from xml by removing underscores & converting the first letter of each word to uppercase (starting from the second word). For instance you can inflate your RecyclerView with: `main.contractList` where the RecyclerView ID in xml is `contract_list`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ContractsListViewModel contractsListViewModel;

   // @BindView(R.id.contractList)
   // RecyclerView contractList;

    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActivityMainBinding main = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);


        // ButterKnife.bind(this);
        main.contractList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this)); // "contract_list" is the id of the RecyclerView in the layout, so data binding removes the "_" and capitalize 1st letter of each word after the first one


        contractsListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ContractsListViewModel.class);
        contractsListViewModel.call();

        contractsListViewModel.contractList.observe(this,contractModels -> {
            adapter = new ContractListAdapter(MainActivity.this, contractModels);
            main.contractList.setAdapter(adapter);
        });

    }
}
```

Back to your question: No need to change your list item layout as you did it perfectly with data binding.

Now, For the adapter:

Like getting a binding object of your activity's layout, also there is a binding object associated to your list item layout that you have to build in the adapter, and you do that in `onCreateViewHolder()` method.

here it's named `ContratBinding`, where your layout is named "contract.xml", if your layout is named list_item.xml, then your object will be `ListItemBinding`.

Then you will customize your `ViewHolder` constructor to accept a `ContratBinding` instance instead of a `View` instance. And send the `binding.getRoot()` to its super class instead of the view; because `getRoot()` returns the root view itself when it comes to use `DataBinding`.

And as you defined a `<variable>` named `contract` in your list item layout, you have to use a `setContract()` method in your adapter to let the xml layout know what this variable is. You can do that typically when you bind data with views in `onBindViewHolder()`.

Your adapter will be

```
public class ContractListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContractListAdapter.ContractViewHolder> {

    List<ContractModel> contracts;
    Context context;

    public ContractListAdapter(Context context, List<ContractModel> contracts){
        this.context = context;
        this.contracts = contracts;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ContractViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contrat, parent, false);
        // return new ContractViewHolder(view);

        ContratBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.contrat, parent, false); // ContratBinding >> as your list item layout named "contrat"
        return new ContractViewHolder(binding);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ContractViewHolder holder, int position) {
      // holder.bind(contracts.get(position));

      holder.binding.setContract(contracts.get(position)); // "Contract" is the variable "name" provided in your <layout><data> within the list item layout


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.contracts.size();
    }

    public class ContractViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    //    @BindView(R.id.courtier)
    //    TextView courtier;

    //    @BindView(R.id.contratImage)
    //    ImageView contractImage;

    private ContratBinding binding; 

    //    public ContractViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView){
    //        super(itemView);
    //        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

    //   }

        public ContractViewHolder(@NonNull ContratBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }



    //    public void bind(ContractModel contractModel){
    //        courtier.setText(contractModel.getCourtier());
    //    }

    }
}
```

I intended to comment out your `ButterKnife` & the code that no longer used with `DataBinding` in order to see the difference

Hope this help you out and feel free to comment out for further help.

Comment: returning new ViewHolder(binding) ? I think you meant return new ContractViewHolder .. also your mContext, I replaced it whith parent.getParent() .. also, I tried to keep my code simple, because I have a button and Image in each row, and click event on the button.. Thanks anyway, I will try your code now

Comment: @TaouBen anytime ... you are right sorry I didn't run it, just customized your code ..